# How to keep a vertical div positioned left against the browser window when resizing and expanding

Tags: html, css

I would appreciate some wisdom here: I have 2 divs side by side each with a width of 50% of its parent div (body set at 200%) - to act like seperate horizontal pages. I would like each div to remain in full view when reducing and expanding the browser window. Currently by expanding the window size when the blue div in viewable the red div gets dragged into view as the scrollbar moves towards the centre of the browser.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #B00;
  min-height: 800px;
  left: 0px;
}

.block2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #00A;
  min-height: 800px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="block1">
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please could you add some more information to your question about what you have tried, and what did/didn't work etc., so we can help you better with your question? In its current state, your question is akin to "I've got some code, and I want it to do this... somebody do it for me?". Adding some more information will help you, and us better understand what you've tried so far, and perhaps point you toward the problem you're having and how to solve it better.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Geoff, I've attempted: floating the divs, setting margins, hiding scrollbars, changing width % to px, setting position, changing the parent div width and position and overflow settings. The horizontal scrollbar behaviour is effectively confusing me.

Comment: You're welcome. If you could include these things you've already tried in your question, along with any relevant results, that would improve your question greatly. Comments can easily get lost in the crowd, and what you sometimes include (like you have with what you've tried) is key to us helping answer your question :)

Answer (score -1):

why not making only one div to be displayed and you add a button or something after clicking it will add some styling effect to hide the visible div and show the hidden one?